# A question about weak convergence in Lp space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose $1 \leq p<\infty$, given $f \in L^p (\mathbb{R})$, define $f_n (x)=n^{1/p} f(nx)$ for n=1,2,3... Prove $f_n$ converges weakly to zero in $L^p$.

Now I can just know the that $ \|f_n\|_p$=$ \|f\|_p$, but cannot prove for any function $g \in L_q$, where $q$ is the conjugate of $p$, the integral converges to zero.

i.e. how to show $\int f_ng$ converges to zero. I'm thinking maybe I can use step functions or continuous functions since they are dense in Lp, so we can approximate, but not sure.

Comment: This is not true for $p=1$. Take $f(x)=g(x)=\chi_{[0,1]}$; then $\int f_n g = 1\not\to0$. The correct range of $p$ is $1<p<\infty$.

Comment: I thought so too since the dual space of $L_1$ is not $L_\infty$

Comment: As a matter of fact, the dual space of $L_1$ is $L_\infty$.

Comment: I think you need to restrict the measure $\mu$ to be $\sigma$ finite